# Android - Determine if a Preference has changed, after user accesses PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, asynchronous, preferenceactivity

I'm making a fairly basic game.  In my preferences, there's an option to change the difficulty setting.   I'd like to be able to somehow, in the main activity that called it, sense if they've changed the difficulty.  (And then restart the game)

I'm having difficulty because of how the preference activity is handled asynchronously.  If I add logic to check the value before and after sending the intent to my PreferenceActivity (from a menu selection), it really doesn't work...

Can someone point me in a proper direction as to either how to serialize a chunk of code normally handled asynchronously, or have an idea of how to sense preferences changed?  Is there a listener class hidden somewhere?

For posterity's sake, here's the code handling the intent and how I'm failing.  (snippet, from inside menu onOptionsItemSelected, inside a switch)

```
case R.id.menuOptions:
    String currentDifficulty = preferences.getString("difficulty","problem!");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, prefs.class);
    startActivity(i);
    if (currentDifficulty.equals(preferences.getString("difficulty","problem!")))
        return true;
    else doNewGame();
    return true;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android allows you to register a preference changed listener. Here's a quick example:

```
public class myClass implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{
    private SharedPreferences settings;

    settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
    {
       // Process it here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.   The example helped me immensely, i cast one as an anonymous listener and wired it up to work for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

[OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html) You can use it to very easily listen for preference changes.

Answer (score 1):

The `OnPreferenceChangeListener` is a good idea, but you could also start your preference activity using `startActivityForResult()`. Your activity is then notified in `onActivityResult()` after the preference activity returns (you should override it to handle preference changes).

Comment: This would work, but you'd have to wait until the preference activity was finished before getting the result, whereas the OnPreferenceChangeListener notifies you immediately.

Comment: This approach has some advantages especially when you want to perform some actions with the changed preferences exactly once. For instance when you configured a server connection it would be very annoying when the app always try to connect when you set the properties for host, port, username or password but all have to be set before this will work.